# How to communicate from embedded site to Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am upgrading our Electron app to version 26 from a very lower version.  In our current app, in order to communicate from our embedded site (our website) to Electron we added window properties to the window object in our preload script in Electron.  With that we were able to use those window properties in our embedded app to send channel messages to main in order to trigger an action in the electron app.
With this upgrade `contextIsolation = true`, `nodeIntegration = false`, and preloading the preload script in `webPreferences` like suggested by Electron.  In the preload script we are using contextBridge to communicate from renderer to main.  With that being said, setting window properties in the preload script doesn't work anymore.  I have also tried to load the preload script through the `<webview>` to expose the `contextBridge` API on the embedded site.  That works when I'm starting the application on my local environment, but once I buld the app that doesn't seem to work.
I have been researching other ways I can communicate from the embedded site to Electron.  I tried using window.postMessage where I post a message and try to have electron listen for that message, but I have not been succesful.
For example:

```
// Embedded website
window.postMessage({'test': 'testing sending message'});
```

Electron app:
renderer.js

```
// renderer.js
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    // context bridge API
    electronApi.ipcRenderer.send('postMessage', event.data);
});
```

Electron app: main.js

```
// main.js
ipcMain.on('postMessage', () => {
   console.log('We received message from renderer');
});
```

Is there anyway of being able to send messages to a channel in electron from an embedded site?

**Update**

I may have come up with a solution on how to inject the window property being set in Electron, but not able figure out how to preloads that window object into renderer so the embedded website can use that window property.

I was able to set the window property by using `executeJavaScript()` in the main process.

```
// renderer.js
webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', (event) => {
    window.api.ipcRenderer.invoke('setWindowProps', webview.getWebContentsId()).then((response) => {
        console.log('Window properties have been set');
        return Promise.resolve();
    }).catch((error) => {
        logError(error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
});

// main.js
ipcMain.handle('setWindowProps', (event, webContentsId) => {
    return getGuestWebContents(webContentsId, event.sender).executeJavaScript(`
        window.sendToElectron = (channel, params) => {
            console.log('send', channel, params);
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, params);
        }
    `);
});

// preload.js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api',
    {
        hasPopOutCapabilities: true,
        supportsNewInteleviewerFlow: true,
        ipcRenderer: {
            on: (channel, callback) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, callback),
            send: (channel, args) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, args),
            invoke: (channel, data, arg) => ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data, arg)
        }
    }
);
```

The issue that the window.sendToElectron property is getting fired before it is defined in Electron.  Is there a way to preload that window object, so it will be there before anything gets executed?
In my webPreferences,

I have `contextIsolation = true` and `nodeIntegration = false` (recommended from Electron v26).

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        x: mainWindowState.x,
        y: mainWindowState.y,
        width: mainWindowState.width,
        height: mainWindowState.height,
        minHeight: 480,
        minWidth: 480,
        id: "mainwindow",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            sandbox: false,
            webviewTag: true,
            plugins: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: preloadPath
        }
    })
```

Comment: How are you embedding that website in your application?

Comment: Why are you embedding a website in your application, to run scripts that call `postMessage`? What messages do you even need to send, from where to where; what problem are you trying to solve? Why not just have your electron app make requests to your web server / HTTP API directly?

Comment: I'm embedding the website using the <webview> tag.

Comment: We are using Electron as a wrapper around our web application.  Before we were using the window object to trigger a ipcRenderer function from within our web application. these window properties were being set in the preloads script.  Since now, contextIsolation = true we can't set the window properties in the preload script.  I was trying to find another way to do this.  I used postMessage as an example I tried but did not work.

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to send requests to the Electron app from the embedded website.    Before a window property was set in Electron where the embedded website can use to trigger an ipcRenderer function
ex. `window.sendToElectron = () => {}` set in `preload.js` and from the embedded website we would call that window property to trigger a ipcRenderer function.  The latest Electron version, from what I have been reading, setting  window property is not allowed or doesn't work in the preload script.  I'm not sure how I can achieve this now.